# Is there a guideline to choosing answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Here is a situation I am in, and I am unsure of how to address it:

I asked a question (on Startups), and two people both work pretty hard to create good answers.  Neither answer is, in my view, complete, but taken together, they answer the question very well.  My question is, how can I reward the responders and indicate to future page visitors that both answers must be read?

I am sorry to ask such a basic question here, but I cannot find guidelines that outline principles that would apply here.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Ironically, I ended up in exactly the same situation here.  Thanks to Bart and Andy.  (They got upvotes)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253361/280611
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253363/280611

Comment: This situation wasn't exactly the same, and much of what I wrote does not apply to your situation, but perhaps you can glean something out of [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287650/how-to-partially-answer-my-own-question-protocol/287651#287651); there are at least a few somewhat related points in it.

Answer (score 4):

Upvote both. You can't accept both, but you can at least leave an indication that both are worthy answers by upvoting them.

And then it's up to you to decide which one should be accepted. The one which comes closest to answering your question. But you are not obliged to accepted anything. So if you can't decide, let it be.

Answer (score 3):

You can reward the responses with upvotes. If you believe both answers must be read, you can add a comment to both answers pointing future readers at the other answer. Be nice and add a direct link to the other answer too. That makes it easier than searching for a specific user's answers if there are more than two total answers.

As for accepting an answer, the [help documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) has this to say:

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally, but not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

If you wish to accept an answer, select the one that is most useful to you. Remember that you do not *have* to accept an answer though.

Comment: The obligatory followup n00b question: How do I direct link to the other answer?

Comment: Under the answer, there is a "Share" link. Click that and copy the URL. You can paste that into a comment under the other answer. It will link directly to the answer. For example, this links to Bart's answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253361/186281